# Find points that lie outside of a series of triangles

Tags: computational-geometry

Suppose there are $n$ triangles on a 2D plane, which don't cross each other and have no common vertex. Suggest an algorithm that gets $n$ points and in $O(n \log n)$ determines the points that don't lie in any triangle. What if the triangles could overlap.

I found some algorithms to determine if a point is inside a triangle or not, but checking this process for all points and triangles is at least $O(n^2)$

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Looks like a job for an R-tree ...

Comment: @badroit Any reservations to fleshing that out into an answer?